# C# custom add in a List

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq

I have the following list of strings :

```
var files = new List<string> {"file0","file1","file2","file3" };
```

I would like to be able to add new files to this list, but if the inserted file is present in the list, I would like to insert custom value that will respect the following format $"{StringToBeInserted}"("{SomeCounter}

For instance : try to add "file0" and "file0" is already I would like to insert "file0(1)". If I try again to add "file0" ... I would like to insert with "file0(2)" and so on ... Also, I would like to provide a consistency, for instance if I delete "file0(1)" ... and try to add again "item0" ... I expect that "item0(1)" to be added. Can someone help me with a generic algorithm ?

Comment: You could probably write some logic that uses a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` as storage, where the key in the dictionary is `file0` f.e. and then a list of used numbers as value. `0` in the list corresponds to `file0`, while everything above `0` (ley's call it X) corresponds to `file0(X)`

Comment: I have some working code, but I didn't know that is mandatory to post it. Thanks !

Comment: "for instance if I delete "file0(1)" ... and try to add again "item0" ... I expect that "item0(1)" to be added". That is very confusing, you do mean "file0" and "file0(1)" don't you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a `HashSet<string>` in this case:

```
var files = new HashSet<string> { "file0", "file1", "file2", "file3" };
string originalFile = "file0";
string file = originalFile;
int counter = 0;
while (!files.Add(file))
{
    file = $"{originalFile}({++counter})";
}
```

If you have to use a list and the result should also be one, you can still use my set approach. Just initialize it with your list and the result list you'll get with `files.ToList()`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should create your own custom class for it, using the data structure you described and a simple class that includes a counter and an output method.

```
void Main()
{
    var items = new ItemCountList();
    items.AddItem("item0");
    items.AddItem("item1");
    items.AddItem("item2");
    items.AddItem("item0");

    items.ShowItems();
}
public class ItemCountList {
    private List<SimpleItem> itemList;
    public ItemCountList() {
        itemList = new List<SimpleItem>();
    }
    public void DeleteItem(string value) {
        var item = itemList.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Value == value);
        if (item != null) {
            item.Count--;
            if (item.Count == 0)
                itemList.Remove(item);
        }
    }
    public void AddItem(string value) {
        var item = itemList.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Value == value);
        if (item != null)
            item.Count++;
        else
            itemList.Add(new SimpleItem {
                Value = value,
                Count = 1
            });
    }
    public void ShowItems() {
        foreach (var a in itemList) {
            Console.WriteLine(a.Value + "(" + a.Count + ")");
        }
    }
}
public class SimpleItem {
    public int Count {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
}
```